# Bootstrap 4, equal spacing between columns with different content widths

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So within my footer I am using `<div class="col">` which creates same width columns, although this is great, the content inside each columns are different widths so visually it looks like the spacing between each column are different widths as shown below:-

[image]

Is there a way to create equal spacing between these columns based on the width of their content so the spacing between each look the same?

Comment: Column's width with spacing working fine, change background color of your columns to see difference.

Comment: Yes I can see that, they are all equal widths, I just thought there may be an easy solution to get the spacing to look the same between the columns based on the width of the content

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to combine `col-auto` (to wrap the columns) with `col` (to space the columns)...

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-auto">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col"> </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col"> </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col"> </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
           ...
        </div>
        <div class="col"> </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col"> </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col"> </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            ...
        </div>
    </div><!--/row-->
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/s4Jk0NBC6a

Answer (score 0):

To adjust spacing, add a class ".no-gutter" inside your footer div tag. And add style in your css file.

```
.no-gutter [class*='col-'] {
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `flexbox` https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

In Bootstrap 4 there are utilities for convenient work with it https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/

**Example:** https://www.codeply.com/go/WQtjXDd8qA